# Problema con rutas en hosting firebase con express

Tags: nodejs, firebase, express, routes

Estoy intentando conectar rutas con archivos html en mi dominio en Firebase.
Lo que sucede es que en el entorno local me funciona pero al momento de hacer el deploy, no toma las rutas personalizadas.

Estoy utilizando NodeJS y Express para realizar el proyecto.
Adjunto 2 imagenes para comparar el ambiente de desarrollo con el de producción.

`https://localhost:3000/comercio`
[image: Ambiente de desarrollo]

`https://midominio.cl/comercio`
[image: Ambiente de producción]
**app.js** (Dentro del directorio public)

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/media',express.static(__dirname + '/public/media'));
app.use('/assets',express.static(__dirname + '/public/assets'));
app.use('/dependencies',express.static(__dirname + '/public/dependencies'));

module.exports = app;
```

**firebase.js** (Dentro del directorio public)

```
    require('dotenv').config();
    
    const { initializeApp, applicationDefault } = require('firebase-admin/app');
    const { getAuth } = require('firebase-admin/auth');
    const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
    
    initializeApp({
        credential: applicationDefault(),
        databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
    });
    
    const db = getFirestore();
    const auth = getAuth();
    
    module.exports = {
        db,
        auth
    };
```

**index.js** (Este se encuentra dentro del directorio routes)

```
    const { Router } = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    
    const router = Router();
    
    // Landing page routes
    router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/..','/public/index.html'));
    });
    router.get('/comercio', async (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/..','/public/commerce.html'));
    });
    router.get('/riders', async (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/..','/public/riders.html'));
    });
    router.get('/privacidad', async (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/..','/public/privacy.html'));
    });
    
    module.exports = router;
```

**Firebase.json** (Creo que por aqui puede ser la próblematica ya que en el ambiente de desarrollo me funciona perfecta la enrutación)

```
    {
      "hosting": {
        "public": "src/public",
        "ignore": [
          "firebase.json",
          "**/.*",
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
```

**Arból de directorios**

```
├─\MiProyecto  
├──\node_modules  
├──\src  
│  ├─\public  
│  ├─\routes  
│  │ └─index.js  
│  ├─app.js  
│  ├─firebase.js  
│  ├─index.js  
├──.env  
├──firebase.json
```

Comment: Yo en lo personal veo demasiados plugins y librerias de terceros

Comment: Acorte partes del codigo para que sea mas leible, lo que busco es hacer funcionar mis rutas en el servidor de firebase una vez haga deploy